NiFi JOLT Transformation spec needed for merging 2 keys into 1 key and keep the value as the 3rd key's value
NiFi JOLT Transformation spec needed for merging 2 keys into 1 key and keep the value as the 3rd key's value.
The spec is not giving desired output. Need jolt spec to get the desired result.
Input:
{
  "options": [
    {
      "method": "EMAIL",
      "type": "ABCD",
      "flag": false,
      "updateSource": "I"
    },
    {
      "method": "ALL",
      "type": "EFGH",
      "flag": false,
      "updateSource": "I"
    },
    {
      "method": "EMAIL",
      "type": "QRST",
      "flag": true,
      "updateSource": "I"
    }
  ]
}

Required Output:
{
  "options" : {
    "EMAIL_ABCD" : false,
    "EMAIL_ABCD_updateSource" : "I",
    "ALL_EFGH" : false,
    "ALL_EFGH_updateSource" : "I",
    "EMAIL_QRST" : true,
    "EMAIL_QRST_updateSource" : "I"
  }
}

spec:
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "options": {
      "*": {
        "method": {
          "*": {
            "@concat((2,method), '_' ,(2,type))": "@(2,flag)"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "*": "&"
  }
}


Any function ( concat in this case ) should be used within a modify spec,
then match the returning attributes in a shift spec such as
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "options": {
        "*": {
          "title1": "=concat(@(1,method),'_',@(1,type))",
          "title2": "=concat(@(1,title1),'_updateSource')"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "options": {
        "*": {
          "@flag": "@title1",
          "@updateSource": "@title2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

Edit : If boolean expressions needed to be replaced as commented, then use the following conditional logic of shift transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "options": {
        "*": {
          "title1": "=concat(@(1,method),'_',@(1,type))",
          "title2": "=concat(@(1,title1),'_updateSource')"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "options": {
        "*": {
          "flag": {
            "true": { "#Y": "&4.@3,title1" },
            "false": { "#N": "&4.@3,title1" }
          },
          "@updateSource": "&2.@title2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]



Thanks so much... It worked.
Subsequently, I want the true/false be transformed as Y/N. I see that there are functions such as toBoolean, toString etc., but nothing that works for this usecase.

Thank you @barbaros. It works good. One small observation is that "options." is missing and hence the whole response is not within the options tag.

My bad, you're right @Sam , just fixed
